# Can a bot delete messages on a dm

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I'm trying to make a clear_dm command. I tried many ways but I couldn't. Probably you guys know how to do it.

I'm going to show my code:

```
@client.command()
async def clear_dm(ctx, arg : int):
    dm = discord.DMChannel
    await ctx.authordm.purge(limit=arg)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author}, your dm with me has been cleared.', delete_after=4)
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Could you include what errors you are receiving with the given code?

Comment: To get the dm channel of a command invoker, use `ctx.author.dm_channel`. However, I'm not confident you can use `purge` on it. I'd write an answer if I could test it but I can't atm so I'm just leaving this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMChannel doesnt have a purge method and you can't delete messages sent by other user in a dm channel. but if you want to clear your bot's messages you can do this:

```
dmchannel = #dm channel you want to clear
async for message in dmchannel.history(limit=100):
    if message.author == client.user: #client.user or bot.user according to what you have named it
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: do i put ctx.author.DMChannel?

Comment: i dont understand what i put here "dmchannel = #dm channel you want to clear"

Comment: `dmchannel = await ctx.author.create_dm()`

Comment: and if the dm alr exists